# Do I need to install Updates from September 2020 individually or I can directly install July 2021

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, administration, patching

We are running SharePoint 2016 Server with

Security update 4484476 for the 64-bit version of SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016  (August 2020 Patch (Language Independent Files)

Security update 4484473 for the 64-bit version of SharePoint Enterprise Server 2016 August 2020 Patch (Language Dependent Files)

If I want to Apply Latest patches (July 2021 Patch), Do I need to install Updates from September 2020 individually or I can directly install July 2021 (Both Dependent and Independent) patches? Please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You  can directly install the latest July 2021 updates.

As per my understanding all new updates are backward compatible with older updates.